# How to make timed requests to a server to avoid rate-limiting using Javascripts setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout, synchronous, rate-limiting

I am trying to use setTimeout in a for loop so that my HTTP requests get sent once per second to avoid rate-limiting. However, it doesn't seem to be working. Could someone please help?

```js
async function initiateSearchExperimental() {
  const json = await getCollections();

  for (let i = 0; i < json.result.data.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(getData(json, i), 1000 * i)
  }
}

function getData(json, i) {
  fetch(`https://howrare.is${json.result.data[i].url}/?for_sale=on&sort_by=rank`).then(function(response) {
    // The API call was successful!
    return response.text();
  }).then(function(html) {

    // Convert the HTML string into a document object
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    var priceArray = getPriceArray(doc.querySelectorAll("div.featured_item"))

    console.log(json.result.data[i].url, curateArrayTwo(priceArray, json.result.data[i]))

  }).catch(function(err) {
    // There was an error
    console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
  });
}
```

Comment: What value does `json` have? And why do you set timeouts instead of using `setInterval(getData, 1000)`?

Comment: json is a json object of collections. I want to iterate through each item in the collection and perform processing on it

Answer (score 0):

No need for await and such

I suggest you DO use setTimeout, but do it in the success of the second fetch

```js
let data;
let cnt = 0;
const getData() {
  if (cnt >= data.length) return; // stop  
  fetch(`https://howrare.is${data[cnt].url}/?for_sale=on&sort_by=rank`)
    .then(function(response) {
      // The API call was successful!
      return response.text();
    }).then(function(html) {
      // Convert the HTML string into a document object
      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
      var priceArray = getPriceArray(doc.querySelectorAll("div.featured_item"))
      console.log(data[cnt].url, curateArrayTwo(priceArray, data[cnt]))
      cnt++
      setTimeout(getData, 1000)
    }).catch(function(err) {
      // There was an error
      console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
    });
};


fetch(collectionurl)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    data = json.result.data;
    getData()
  });
```